# three js loading manager. how to create separate groups with separate callbacks?

Tags: three.js

I have multiple groups of texture images (at different times) to load into a three js scene, and would like to get callbacks ***when each separate group is loaded***.  The groups may overlap in time.

If there was just one group, I could do this:

```
// FETCH BEADS NEEDED and rebuild display if needed. Return qty of beads requested
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager( function() {

    // this onLoad callback is executed when both textures are loaded

} );

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );
var texture1 = loader.load( 'texture1.png' );
var texture2 = loader.load( 'texture2.png' );
```

This will work fine for the first group consisting of texture1.png and texture2.png.   But now I have a separate group of texture3.png and texture4.png ...

What I need is two callbacks, one when texture1.png and texture2.png are both loaded, ***and a second callback*** when texture3 and texture4.png are loaded.

I could create a new TextureLoader for the second one, but in fact I will have many groups and don't want to have hundreds or thousands of TextureLoaders lying around and leaking memory.

Should I delete each one in its onLoad callback?  Or what?

Thanks and best regards, jb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loading manager has an `.onLoad` property where you can assign a callback for when its elements have finished loading. You can assign this at any time, it doesn't have to be set when initializing, so just re-assign it before you start loading a new group, and it should have the behavior you're looking for. You can read [more about the `.onLoad` property in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager.onLoad):

```js
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);

function loadGroup1() {
    manager.onLoad = () => {
        console.log("Group 1 complete");
    };
    texLoader.load("img1.png");
    texLoader.load("img2.png");
}

function loadGroup2() {
    manager.onLoad = () => {
        console.log("Group 2 loaded");
    };
    texLoader.load("img3.png");
    texLoader.load("img4.png");
}

function loadGroup3() {
    manager.onLoad = () => {
        console.log("Group 3 finished");
    };
    texLoader.load("img5.png");
    texLoader.load("img6.png");
}
```

Just make sure the previous group has finished loading before starting the next group, otherwise you'll overwrite the `onLoad` function prematurely.

#### Edit

An alternative method that doesn't require staggering the loads:

```js
var texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var loadTracker = [];

function loadTex(url, groupNo) {
    // Start a new group if it doesn't exist
    if (loadTracker[groupNo] === undefined) {
        loadTracker[groupNo] = 1;
    }
    // Add 1 to group if it already exists
    else {
        loadTracker[groupNo] ++;
    }

    // Load texture
    texLoader.load(url, () => {
        // Subtract 1 from group when load is finished
        loadTracker[groupNo] --;

        // When count reaches 0, group has finished loading
        if (loadTracker[groupNo] === 0) {
            console.log("Group number " + groupNo + " has finished loading");
        }
    });
}

// Trigger loads with image URL, and group they belong to
loadTex("img1.png", 0);
loadTex("img2.png", 0);
loadTex("img3.png", 1);
loadTex("img4.png", 1);
loadTex("img5.png", 1);
loadTex("img6.png", 2);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks Marquizzo.   My problem is that I CANNOT make sure the previous group has finished loading before starting the next group.  My groups start asynchronously, and thus finish in a different order than they were started, and (as I mentioned) *** the groups may overlap in time. *** ... Any further suggestions?  Cheers jb

Comment: @den232 Well, this isn't much of a Three.js question, but more of a logic question. You just have to create something that keeps count of how many images belong to each group, subtract 1 when each load is complete, and when that count reaches 0, that means all images have finished loading. I added an example above using an array, but there are probably dozens of ways to achieve this.

Comment: Actually no, I want an alert when EACH GROUP is complete. Since I have temporally overlapping groups, it might be forever before I get the message that a long-ago finished group is complete. 

Yes, I can ignore the loading manager altogether and roll my own by building separate sets of pending items and all. I was hoping that the loading manager might help, but it is looking to be not so helpful after all.

Comment: @den232 Did you try my second solution? That’s exactly what it does. It alerts you when each group finishes, not just all of them. Just change the second number in `loadTex()` and it’ll belong to a different group.

Comment: I missed that edit.  Edit is a pretty, clean solution.  Thanks so much!  Cheers jb